# VBA Selenium Click not supported

Tags: vba, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to click a button on a website using VBA Selenium.

```
Dim driver As New webdriver
driver.Start "ie"
driver.get fileLocation
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:20")
Dim By As New By, button As Object

Set button = driver.findElementsByXPath("//*[@id='col_esq']/div/form/div[6]/div/a[2]")
button.Click
```

This causes an error of `Run-time error 438, Object doesn't support this property or method` at the last code. How can I solve this?

How I got Xpath: I went to the website and right-clicked on the button, used inspect function to find codes attached to the button, right-clicked and copied Xpath. The codes are pretty much nested and the button has no id nor name.

[Edit]
I did `Msgbox button.count` which displayed 0. I am wondering how the item cannot be found with Xpath I copied from the source codes. Any idea?

Comment: `driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='col_esq']/div/form/div[6]/div/a[2]")`   Click is a method of a single webElement, not a webElements collection.

Comment: Thanks! So doesn't this code extract a single webElement?

Comment: Welcome. No. Because you used the `FindElements` with an `s`.

Comment: you have edited the question into a hybrid. The title no longer matches what your new question is. I suggest you properly update the question, including title, to match what you now want to know. Then we will need the relevant html and ideally an url if public (though looks like maybe you are using a local file?).

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks. Now it has NoSuchElement Exception so it is definitely a different question. I am going to post a new one (The url is public).